# Bring window to front when loaded (Caliburn.Micro)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

**What is the situation:**

I'm working on a C# WPF application with the MVVM pattern. I'm using Caliburn.Micro and MahApps.Metro.

I have a list of ViewModels in ViewModelA:

```
ObservableCollection<ViewModelB> ViewModelList { get; set; }  // short version
```

There is a ListView in my corresponding View that binds to this list:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding }" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The ViewModels in the list are displayed by a ContentControl.

In ViewModelB there is an event that gets called on a double click on the corresponding View (MetroWindow):

```
public void OnDoubleClick()
{
    var windowManager = IoC.Get<IWindowManager>();
    windowManager.ShowWindow(new ViewModelC());
}
```

The WindowManager shows a new non modal window for me (View of ViewModelC).

---

**What is the problem:**

The non modal window is not focused and behind my main window after it's shown by WindowManager.

I tried a lot of settings for my window like ShowActivated, Owner, Topmost...
When I set the owner to my main window then the shown window behaves like Topmost is set to true.

I just want the window to appear on front of my main window (not Topmost=true) and focused.

---

**Unsatisfying solution:**

I can replace the ContentControl with the View I want to display and get rid of the list of ViewModels. If I do that I can listen to the MouseDoubleClick event of my ListView and get the selected element with the property SelectedIndex.

If I do it that way the shown window behaves like I want it to (on top, focused).

But ViewModelB needs a lot of logic and I want to encapsulate it.

---

Best regards, mash

Comment: I ask in the blue because i have done a mvvm with mahapps too, but I havn´t any problems because I use UserControls on a MainWindow so I don´t have to set the new windows ontop. If this could help you, I can show you how to use it with UserControls

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I know how to use MahApps and UserControls and stuff... I also know how to open new MetroWindows with Caliburn.Micro. My problem only occurs at this particular part of my code. If I open the MetroWindow somewhere else it behaves like expected.